Screen Flow Conditional Visibility Issue
We have created Screen flow where we have added multiple components on the screen:
Section 1: Displayed input fields to capture users first name, last name or email
Section 2: Embedded LWC component to do address validation:

Section 3: Added form fields to capture the bank details. Here we have added conditional visibility based on the variables populated in section 3:

We are facing issue in configuring the conditional visibility for section3. Even though section 2 variable is populated correctly, we are not able to conditionally display section3.

Do you have checked this? - https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_considerations_design_conditional_visibility.htm&type=5  -https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_considerations_feature_variable.htm&type=5
